# Google script create event - issues with event description

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

This is probably a `Type` issue, but I just can't seem to solve it.

The code, running from Sheets, based on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options):

```
var eventdescription = 'test';
    
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarid).createEvent(
    eventtitle,
    startfull,
    endfull,
    {description: eventdescription},
    {location: eventaddress.toString()}
);
```

The error:

> Cannot find method createEvent(string,object,object,object,object).

I had a similar issue with the `location` but this was solved by adding `toString()`. With the `description`, I cannot seem to find a solution. Isn't it a `string` as well? It doesn't work with or without the `toString()`.

Omitting the `{description: eventdescription},` allows the script to run with no issues, but of course with no description in the event.

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The advanced options need to go all within the same curly brackets:

```js
var eventdescription = 'test';
    
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarid).createEvent(
    eventtitle,
    startfull,
    endfull,
    {description: eventdescription, location: eventaddress.toString()}
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed as per your suggestion but now I get another error Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object)

Comment: What is eventdescription? Is it a variable of type string? If not - convert it to one!

Comment: My bad, it was indeed another silly mistake in a long line of such :) @ziganotschka you've been 100% correct and it solved the issue. Thanks!